# Connect database and retrieve values using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want to connect to the database and retrieve value from database using javascript as I built a javascript bargraph. Below is my code if someone can look into that and help me.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db('sarc', $link);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT 73');

$val = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$val = $val[0];

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="progressbar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="progressbar.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.my_progress_bar {
border-width: 0px;
}

</style>

<div id="my_progress_bar_1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var currentValue = [<?php echo $val; ?>];
var myProgressBar = null
var timerId = null
function loadProgressBar(){
myProgressBar = [
     new ProgressBar("my_progress_bar_1",{
         height: 400,
         width: 129,
         orientation: ProgressBar.Orientation.Vertical,
         direction: ProgressBar.Direction.BottomToTop,
         animationStyle: ProgressBar.AnimationStyle.StaticFull,
         showLabel: false,
         imageUrl: 'images/bottle-in.png',
         markerUrl: 'images/marker-bottle.png',
         extraClassName: {
             wrapper: 'my_progress_bar',
             left: 'my_progress_bar',
             right: 'my_progress_bar',
             middle: 'my_progress_bar',
             marker: 'my_progress_bar',
             parent: 'my_progress_bar',
             background: 'my_progress_bar'
         },
     })
 ];

 myProgressBar[0].setValue(currentValue);
}

loadProgressBar();
</script>
```

This code is displaying blank page when I run it. Can anybody help me pls

Comment: what is your server side technology? PHP? ASP.NET?

Comment: My server side technology is PHP

Comment: For your case I'd say you can't read database using JavaScript, read it using php, JavaScript should access the PHP page and get the value.

Comment: add the code for Progressbar.js

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a jump for someone unfamiliar with both AJAX and jQuery.  I would recommend you start here:

**AJAX Tutorial**: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

**jQuery Tutorial**: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

After you're familiar with those two, you'll want something like this:

**File 1**: ajax_landing.php

```
// This file needs to search your database using PHP, and echo the results.
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT myCol FROM myTable WHERE condition = value"));
echo json_encode($data);

// This should output something like...
{ myCol: 73 }
```

**File 2**: chart_page.html (or .php)

```
<script>
$.getJSON("ajax_landing.php", function(response) {
    var value = response['myCol'];

    example_10(value);
});
</script>
```

Of course this is only scratching the surface, but will hopefully point you in the right direction.

Please no downvotes for linking w3schools.  They aren't *that* terrible... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing this javascript in a web browser, as I assume you are, then the most common way to get data from the database is via the server.  And this means that you need some sort of dynamic server.  In the Java world, this would be a Servlet container and you would most likely use a web application framework on top of that servelt container to help out.  You javasript would make an ajax call to the server, and the java code would connect to the DB, then prepare an ajax appropriate response out of that data, such as json or xml.

Does this help?  Note, there are other types of db's you can probably hit directly from the javascript, but that's kind of advanced topics.  I'd need more requirements from you to know whether a more specialized case is called for.

Comment: I havent use java before for database. I am using PHP to build dynamic sites

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no easy answer to this @Rajan, even though AJAX seem complecated it is your friend here. You have to add a PHP page which read your data from db and return it as JSON (not a big page with all the HTML, just a **JSON** string, ex `{ value: 73 }`, then use a client side JavaScript library (such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) to access that page, using ajax and pass the value to your function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourserver/phppage.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) { example_10(data.value); }
});
```

This code will not work as it is, but hopefully it will serve you as a guide. You need to modify example_10 function to accept parameters as well. :)

We can't write the entire program for you. But we can of course help at points where you get stuck. So you have to start your self.

Comment: Thanks @BuddhiP for your help. It was just that I was new to javascript and have never called a variable in javascript, so if you can just tell me like it is same as php select function and phppage.php is the db connect file right

Comment: is there any variable which I have to declare before this code as this code is not workin directly

Comment: Sorry can u provide me with some more help I entered this data just above function but I dont know how to do that it woud be great if you can help me pls

Comment: i have edited the code i just copied and pasted it and tried with different sort of things but still it not working so I just pasted the function over here

Comment: What should I write in var data [73]; which variable should I use in here

Comment: i tried really hard but now success. Can u please help me its really tough as I dont know anything about jquery. PLease its would really very helpful if you can help me.

Comment: Ok, tell me how frequently this variable of yours change? Does that change every minute, or does it change once per for example? I'm trying to see if you really need.AJAX or is it enough to load this variable at page rendering and pass it down with rest of the HTML?

Comment: I tried and have written the code but When I run it on server it just gives me back a blank page. No errors nothing wrong but I dont know whats heppening. I am editing my post with the new code if anybody can help me out with that

Comment: @Rajan, what progressbar component you use? is it from jQuery UI? send me the link?